# Joining multiple files iteratively in Bash

Tags: bash, data-cleaning

I have files in the following format:

in file0.txt

```
234 ABC
123 KJN
245 MDJ
274 FWX
```

in file1.txt

```
45 ABC
1 KJN
546 MDJ
456 FWX
```

similarly, I have 24 files in total from file0.txt to file23.txt
I am trying to join all these files into one file based on the 2nd column as the key.
Desired output is:

```
ABC 234 45
KJN 123 1
MDJ 245 546
FWX 274 456
```

I wrote something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<=23;i++)
 do
     if[ -e file$i ]
       then
             join -1 2 -2 2 file$i.txt file`expr $i +1`.txt > fileJoined.txt
             fileJoined.txt > file`expr $i +1`.txt
     fi
 done
```

The logic fails after the first run as the joined file structure is changed and the join tries to join it on second column . Please suggest how to correct  this. Also is there any better way to achieve this? Please note I had carefully used a space in **if [ -e file$i ]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$2]=a[$2] (a[$2]==""?"":OFS) $1}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
ABC 234 45
FWX 274 456
MDJ 245 546
KJN 123 1
```

The script stores records to memory so you should have enough memory to handle all required files. Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$2]=a[$2] (a[$2]==""?"":OFS) $1  # hash all records to a, index with $2
}
END {                                  # after hashing all records
    for(i in a)                        # go thru all of them in random order
        print i,a[i]                   # and output them
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have 24 such files as shown in file0.txt and file1.txt. Can I get one complete file in the end in the required format with awk?

Comment: Just add all needed files to the end of the script or use wildcards and redirect the output to a new file, like `awk '...' file* > newfile`

Comment: Ok, so this works but the only problem is the first record displayed after the key is essentially the last record. So for example if I get: ABC 234 45 2343 12,    the real order should be : ABC 45 2343 12 234

Comment: The script appends the values (`$1`) in the order it gets them (`a[$2]=a[$2] OFS $1`). You can change the order by processing the files in desired order (`awk '...' file3 file1 file2 ..`).

Comment: this is quite helpful, can you please explain the line $ awk '{
    a[$2]=a[$2] (a[$2]==""?"":OFS) $1

Comment: For example, if `a["ABC"]` is empty put an empty (`""`) before the value in `$1` (ie. `a["ABC"]= "" "234"`). Else put `OFS` before it (`OFS` is space by default ie. `a["ABC"]="234" OFS "45"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped